# How to add space after characters entered in the textbox upto max length

Tags: vb.net

`Imports System.Net
Imports System.Net.Sockets
Imports System.Threading

Public Class Form1

```
Private client As TCPControl

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    GroupBox2.Enabled = False
    GroupBox3.Enabled = False
    send.Enabled = False
    send.BackColor = Color.Gray
    ComboBox1.Enabled = False

    porttextbox.Text = "1025"

End Sub


Private Sub connect_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles connect.Click
    Label24.Text = row1.Text.Length
    Label25.Text = row2.Text.Length
    Label26.Text = row3.Text.Length
    Label27.Text = row4.Text.Length
    Label28.Text = row5.Text.Length
    Label29.Text = row6.Text.Length
    Label30.Text = row7.Text.Length
    Label31.Text = row8.Text.Length
    Label32.Text = row9.Text.Length
    Label33.Text = row10.Text.Length
    Label34.Text = row11.Text.Length
    Label35.Text = row12.Text.Length
    Label36.Text = row13.Text.Length
    Label37.Text = row14.Text.Length
    Label38.Text = row15.Text.Length
    Label39.Text = row16.Text.Length
    Label40.Text = row17.Text.Length
    Label41.Text = row18.Text.Length
    Label42.Text = row19.Text.Length
    Label43.Text = row20.Text.Length
    If iptextbox.Text = "" Or porttextbox.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Please Enter valid IP or PORT NO.")
    Else
        Try
            client = New TCPControl(iptextbox.Text, porttextbox.Text)
            GroupBox2.Enabled = True
            GroupBox3.Enabled = True
            send.Enabled = False
            ComboBox1.Enabled = True

            iptextbox.ReadOnly = True
            porttextbox.ReadOnly = True

            If client.client.Connected = True Then
                MsgBox("CONNECTED" & vbNewLine & "WRITE TEXT")

            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub check()
    If myinterval > 1 Then

        Button1.Enabled = True
        disconnect.Enabled = True

    End If

End Sub

Private Sub send_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles send.Click
    send.Enabled = True
    GroupBox2.Enabled = False
    GroupBox3.Enabled = False
    If client.client.Connected = True Then
        Timer1.Start()

        If BackgroundWorker1.IsBusy = False Then

            BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox("PLEASE CONNECT")

    End If

End Sub

Sub mydelay()
    Dim icount As Long = 1
    For icount = 1 To 10
        icount = icount + 1
    Next
End Sub

Dim icount As Long = 0
Dim len As Integer
Dim c As Integer
Dim tcount As Long = 26


Private Sub page1()

    If client.client.Connected = True Then
        If BackgroundWorker1.IsBusy = False Then
            BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
        End If

        'client.Send(row1.Text & vbNewLine)
        'If row1.Text.Length < 26 Then       ' For comparing character in textbox and adding spaces if less than maximum size of TB - 24/5/2019(10:14 am
        'For i As Integer = 1 To row1.MaximumSize
        'For i As Integer = row1.Text.Length + 1 To 26
        'row1.AppendText(" ")

        'Next
        'End If
        'If row1.Text.Length > tcount Then
        'row1.Text = row1.Text.Substring(0, tcount)
        'row1.Text = Trim(row1.Text)
        'Else

        'row1.Text = row1.Text.PadRight(tcount, " ")
        'End If

        If row1.Text.Length < 26 Then
            Dim SelStart As Integer = row1.SelectionStart
            row1.Text = row1.Text.PadRight(26).Substring(0, 26)
            row1.Select(SelStart, 0)


        End If
        client.Send(row1.Text)

        'If row2.Text.Length > tcount Then
        'row2.Text = Trim(row2.Text)
        'row2.Text = row2.Text.Substring(0, tcount)
        'Else
        '   For i As Integer = row2.Text.Length + 1 To 26
        '  row2.AppendText(" ")
        'Else
        ' Next
        'row2.Text = row2.Text.PadRight(tcount, " ")
        'row2.Text = row2.Text.Replace(" ", "")
        'End If
        If row2.Text.Length < 26 Then
            Dim SelStart As Integer = row2.SelectionStart
            row2.Text = row2.Text.PadRight(26).Substring(0, 26)
            row2.Select(SelStart, 0)


        End If
        client.Send(row2.Text)




        'If row2.TextLength < 26 Then
        'For i As Integer = row2.Text.Length + 1 To 26
        'row2.AppendText(" ")
        '
        'Next
        'End If
        'If row3.Text.Length > tcount Then
        'row3.Text = row3.Text.Substring(0, tcount)
        'row3.Text = Trim(row3.Text)
        'Else

        'row3.Text = row3.Text.PadRight(tcount, " ")
        'End If

        If row3.Text.Length < 26 Then
            Dim SelStart As Integer = row3.SelectionStart
            row3.Text = row3.Text.PadRight(26).Substring(0, 26)
            row3.Select(SelStart, 0)


        End If


        client.Send(row3.Text)

        'If row4.TextLength <= 26 Then
        'For i As Integer = row4.Text.Length + 1 To 26
        ''row4.AppendText(" ")

        ''Next
        'End If
        If row4.Text.Length > tcount Then
            row4.Text = row4.Text.Substring(0, row4.MaxLength)
        Else
            row4.Text = row4.Text.PadRight(row4.MaxLength, " ")
        End If

        client.Send(row4.Text)

        client.Send(row5.Text & vbNewLine + row6.Text & vbNewLine + row7.Text & vbNewLine + row8.Text & vbNewLine + row9.Text & vbNewLine + vbTab & row10.Text & vbNewLine)

        End If

End Sub

Private Sub page2()

    If client.client.Connected = True Then
        If BackgroundWorker1.IsBusy = False Then

            BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
        End If

        client.Send(row11.Text & vbNewLine)
        client.Send(row12.Text & vbNewLine)
        client.Send(row13.Text & vbNewLine + row14.Text & vbNewLine + row15.Text & vbNewLine + row16.Text & vbNewLine + row17.Text & vbNewLine + row18.Text & vbNewLine + row19.Text & vbNewLine + vbTab & row20.Text & vbNewLine)
        'Label44.Text = "YOU CAN EDIT OR CLOSE"

    End If

End Sub

Dim myinterval As Long

Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged

    send.Enabled = True

    send.BackColor = Color.Green

    If Me.ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
        myinterval = 6000
    ElseIf Me.ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 1 Then
        myinterval = 120000
    ElseIf Me.ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 2 Then
        myinterval = 180000
    ElseIf Me.ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 3 Then
        myinterval = 240000
    ElseIf Me.ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 4 Then
        myinterval = 300000
    ElseIf Me.ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 5 Then
        myinterval = 360000

    End If

End Sub

Dim counter As Integer = 0

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
    CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False

    'counter += 1
    For counter As Integer = 0 To myinterval - 1
        If client.client.Connected = True Then
            If BackgroundWorker1.CancellationPending = True Then
                e.Cancel = True
                Exit For
            End If

            'counter = 0
            page1()
            Thread.Sleep(myinterval)
            page2()
            Thread.Sleep(myinterval)
            'Else
            'counter = 0
        End If
        Timer1.Interval = myinterval
        myinterval = myinterval + 1
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

    If BackgroundWorker1.IsBusy = False Then

        BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
    Else

        If BackgroundWorker1.WorkerSupportsCancellation Then

            BackgroundWorker1.CancelAsync()
        End If

    End If

    row10.ScrollToCaret()

    'If Label49.Location.X + Label49.Width < 0 Then
    'Label49.Location = New Point(Label49.Location.X, Label49.Location.Y = 1)
    'Else
    'Label49.Location = New Point(Label49.Location.X - 3, Label49.Location.Y)
    'End If

    'Label47.Text = row10.Text
    'Label48.Text = row20.Text
    'If Label47.Right = 0 Then
    'Label47.Left = Width
    'Else
    'Label47.Left -= 1
    'End If
    'If Label48.Right = 0 Then
    'Label48.Left = Width
    'Else
    'Label48.Left -= 1
    'End If
    'client.Send(Label47.Text)
    'client.Send(Label48.Text)
End Sub

Private Sub disconnect_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles disconnect.Click
    If iptextbox.Text = "" Or porttextbox.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Connection not established")
    Else
        Try
            client.client.Close()
            client.Datastream.Flush()
            GroupBox2.Enabled = False
            GroupBox3.Enabled = False
            send.Enabled = False
            send.BackColor = Color.Gray
            ComboBox1.Enabled = False

            iptextbox.ReadOnly = False
            porttextbox.ReadOnly = False

            MsgBox("Connection Close")

            Timer1.Stop()

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Disconnected")
        End Try
    End If
End Sub


Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
    Try
        If client.client.Connected = True Then
            client.Datastream.Close()
            client.client.Close()

        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Close the Utility")
    End Try

End Sub


Private Sub row1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles row1.TextChanged
    If row1.Text.Length < 26 Then
        Dim SelStart As Integer = row1.SelectionStart
        row1.Text = row1.Text.PadRight(26).Substring(0, 26)
        row1.Select(SelStart, 0)


    End If
    Label24.Text = row1.Text.length
End Sub

Private Sub row2_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles row2.TextChanged
    Label25.Text = row2.Text.Length
End Sub

Private Sub row3_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles row3.TextChanged
    Label26.Text = row3.Text.Length
End Sub

Private Sub row4_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles row4.TextChanged
    Label27.Text = row4.Text.Length
End Sub

Private Sub row5_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles row5.TextChanged
    Label28.Text = row5.Text.Length
End Sub


Private Sub row6_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles row6.TextChanged
    Label29.Text = row6.Text.Length
End Sub

Private Sub row7_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles row7.TextChanged
    Label30.Text = row7.Text.Length
End Sub

Private Sub row8_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles row8.TextChanged
    Label31.Text = row8.Text.Length
End Sub

Private Sub row9_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles row9.TextChanged
    Label32.Text = row9.Text.Length
End Sub

Private Sub row10_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles row10.TextChanged
    Label33.Text = row10.Text.Length

End Sub

Private Sub row11_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles row11.TextChanged
    Label34.Text = row11.Text.Length
End Sub

Private Sub row12_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles row12.TextChanged
    Label35.Text = row12.Text.Length
End Sub

Private Sub row13_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles row13.TextChanged
    Label36.Text = row13.Text.Length
End Sub

Private Sub row14_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles row14.TextChanged
    Label37.Text = row14.Text.Length
End Sub

Private Sub row15_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles row15.TextChanged
    Label38.Text = row15.Text.Length
End Sub

Private Sub row16_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles row16.TextChanged
    Label39.Text = row16.Text.Length
End Sub

Private Sub row17_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles row17.TextChanged
    Label40.Text = row17.Text.Length
End Sub

Private Sub row18_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles row18.TextChanged
    Label41.Text = row18.Text.Length
End Sub

Private Sub row19_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles row19.TextChanged
    Label42.Text = row19.Text.Length
End Sub

Private Sub row20_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles row20.TextChanged
    Label43.Text = row20.Text.Length
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    GroupBox2.Enabled = True
    GroupBox3.Enabled = True

    If client.client.Connected = True Then
        Try
            client.Datastream.Flush()
            client.Datastream.Close()
            Timer1.Stop()

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(" Cannot close")
        End Try
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles edit.Click

    Password.Show()
    If iptextbox.Text = "" Or porttextbox.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Please Enter valid IP or PORT NO.")
    Else
        Try
            client = New TCPControl(iptextbox.Text, porttextbox.Text)
            GroupBox2.Enabled = True

            GroupBox3.Enabled = True
            send.Enabled = False
            ComboBox1.Enabled = True

            iptextbox.ReadOnly = True
            porttextbox.ReadOnly = True

            If client.client.Connected = True Then


            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End If


    Me.Enabled = False


End Sub
```

End Class

`Total length of textbox is 26 character .
when i enter characters < 26 it should add spaces .
Is there any solution ?
row1 abcdefghijklmnop.......upto 26 
row2 abcdefghijklmnop.......upto 26 
row3 abcdefghijklmnop.......upto 26 
..
.
.
..
.
.
upto row10
This is expected output

actual output :
row1 abcdefghijklmnop.......upto 26 
row2 abcdefghijklmnop.......upto 25 and 1 space
row3 2 spaces +abcdefghijklmnop.......upto 24

Please help me with the same

Comment: Try to find how many space do you want to add. Then add using `+ space(numberofspace)`

Comment: I cant have defined no. of characters ... it will be fed by user.

Answer (score 0):

You have to padrighz

```
Dim str as string = "sometext"
Dim pad as char = " "
str = str.PadRight(26, pad)
```

Comment: There's no need to specify a `Char` to pad with because the default is spaces.

Comment: That code is not quite right because, like pretty much all `String` methods, `PadRight` doesn't affect the existing instance but rather returns a new instance.  You should use `str = str.PadRight(26)`.

Comment: Pad right is not helping me...i have even trimmed the excess data if any                     If row1.Text.Length > tcount Then
                row1.Text = row1.Text.Substring(0, row1.MaxLength)
            Else

                row1.Text = row1.Text.PadRight(row1.MaxLength, " ")
            End If

            client.Send(row1.Text)

Comment: I think client.send is the problem. Please also so source code for everything you got on client. And you can edit your own post and add the the source code

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyUp(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyUp
    If TextBox1.Text.Length < 26 Then
        Dim SelStart As Integer = TextBox1.SelectionStart
        TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.PadRight(26).Substring(0, 26)
        TextBox1.Select(SelStart, 0)
    End If
End Sub
```